# Deliver PDF through iframe using HTTPS .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, iframe, https

I am trying to display a PDF in an iframe while using HTTPS and hosting it via IIS.  This is all running on my local network.  Everything works fine when I use normal HTTP but once I turn HTTPS on it prompts a security warning when the page is loaded saying the iframe isn't being delivered via HTTPS and I can't find where that would be changed.  Any suggestions on how to get that iframe to deliver PDF's via HTTPS?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is the IFrame pointing to a page served through HTTPS? Are all static resources on the page served through HTTPS rather than HTTP?

Comment: The iFrame is embedded in a site that is hosted via IIS and is hosted via IIS.